# Groupby values in one column the result of dividing the sum of column b by the sum of column A

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with multiple columns and thousands of rows.  One column contains segmentation classification (ScoreSeg).  Other columns contain different values related to a item in that row.  I would like to groupby on 'ScoreSeg', (the sum of column 'PredMbrs' ) / (sum column b: 'EstMbrs')

I tried the following:

```
pr.groupby('ScoreSeg')['PredMbrs'].sum()/pr['EstMbrs'].sum()
```

Actual results are:

```
ScoreSeg
1-3     0.131708
4-5     0.060665
6-6     0.609900
7-8     0.167228
9-11    0.100284
```

Name: PredMbrs, dtype: float64

The Expected results are:

```
1-3 0.954568997
4-5 1.011131346
6-6 1.056760686
7-8 1.176788844
9-11    1.211452952
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not chain the `groupby` with two separate functions

```
s=(pr.groupby('ScoreSeg')['PredMbrs','EstMbrs'].sum())
s['PredMbrs']/s['EstMbrs']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use apply() on groupby():

```
df.groupby(''ScoreSeg'').apply(lambda x: x['PredMbrs'].sum()/
                           float(x['EstMbrs'].sum()))
```